# How to use bitset function in MATLAB to modify multiple bits simultaneously

Tags: matlab

```
>> a = 255

a =

   255

>> bitset(a,1,0)

ans =

   254
```

here the first bit is set to 0 so we get 11111110 equivalent to 254

```
>> bitset(a,[1,2],0)

ans =

   254   253
```

here the 1st bit and 2nd bit are being set to 0 seperately. Hence we get 
11111110 equivalent to 254
11111101 equivalent to 253

how to get 11111100 equivalent to 252?

Comment: I would probably just do `bitand(a, 0xfc)`. How many different bits do you expect to mask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply [`bitset`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bitset.html) twice:

```
bitset(bitset(a, 1, 0), 2, 0)
```

The order of application should not matter.

Alternatively, you can use the fact that `bitset` is an equivalent to applying the correct sequence of [`bitand`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bitand.html), [`bitor`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bitor.html) and [`bitcmp`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bitcmp.html) operations.

Since you are interested in turning off multiple bits, you can do

```
bitand(bitset(a, 1, 0), bitset(a, 2, 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-liner:

```
a = 255;
bits = [1,2];
bitand(a,bitcmp(sum(2.^(bits-1)),'uint32'))
```

Taken apart:

```
b = sum(2.^(bits-1))
```

computes the integer with the given bits set. Note that `bits` must not contain duplicate elements. Use `unique` to enforce this: `bits = unique(bits)`.

```
c = bitcmp(b,'uint32')
```

computes the 32-bit complement of the above. ANDing with the complement resets the given bits.

```
bitand(a,c)
```

computes the binary AND of the input number and the integer with the given bits turned off.

Setting bits is easier:

```
a = 112;
bits = [1,2];
bitor(a,sum(2.^(bits-1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe most explicit, easiest to understand, you can convert to a string representing binary and then do the operations there, then convert back.

```
a = 255
bin_a = flip(dec2bin(a))  % flip to make bigendian
bin_a([1, 2]) = '0'
a = bin2dec(flip(bin_a))
```

Comment: it's already in binary. You're suggesting conversion to a string instead. Not saying it's wrong, just suggesting you make the terminology more precise.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little recursive function based on the answer from @Mad Physicist that will allow zeroing of any number of bits  in data . Thanks for the original info.  The recursion is probably dead obvious to most people but it might help somebody out.

```
function y = zero_nbits(x, n)

   y = bitset(x, n, 0)

   if n > 1
      y = zero_nbits(y, n-1);
   end

end
```